# TextView doesn't change visually, but the date it keeps is correct

Tags: java, android, textview

After login, I want to change text in TextView near profile on name_user.

But it doesn't change textView visually.

It is worth to mention, that when outputting (Toast), it gives out the data that is needed, but does not visually display it. Everything is fine with the TextView parameters (I think), because if you set the finished text in the parameters( i mean android:text="smth"), it visually displays it.

Java code:

```
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
yourLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_navigation_header, null); 
profileName = yourLayout.findViewById(R.id.profName); //
Intent intent = getIntent(); // Get data from previous activity.
String name_user = intent.getStringExtra("name");
String email_user = intent.getStringExtra("email");
String password_user = intent.getStringExtra("password");
profileName.setText(name_user); //0 changes, textView still don't change.
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu2); 

DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), profileName.getText().toString(),
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); // for debug, it works and show profileName that contains name_user, but.       
toast.show();


findViewById(R.id.imageMenu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
});
}`
```

Part of main XML

```
`<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigationView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_navigation_header"// layour_navigation_header -here is TextView
app:menu='@menu/navigation_menu'
android:layout_gravity="start"/>`
```

Part of layour_navigation_header with TextView that I need to change.

```
`<TextView
android:id="@+id/profName"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:text="Temporary"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/viewSupporter"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageProfile"/>`
```

Hope you could help me

I tried to move

```
`yourLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_navigation_header, null); 
profileName = yourLayout.findViewById(R.id.profName); //
Intent intent = getIntent(); // Get data from previous activity.
String name_user = intent.getStringExtra("name");
String email_user = intent.getStringExtra("email");
String password_user = intent.getStringExtra("password");
profileName.setText(name_user); //0 changes, textView still don't change`
```

before

```
`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu2);`
```

but final result remains the same. It contains data, but not visually displays it.

Answer (score 0):

You're inflating `layout_navigation_header` layout and setting a value in one of its textviews. But you never seem to place the layout on screen, the layout instance simply gets discarded.

What gets displayed is the `activity_menu2` layout you inflate and set as content view with `setContentView()`. If that layout includes `layout_navigation_header` or its look-a-like with some mechanism, it's not the same instance you inflated earlier.

To solve the issue, just call `setContentView()` to set your desired layout, call `findViewById()` to find the textview and set a text to it.